# Mi php no recibe datos del formulario

Tags: php, mysqli, formularios

Estoy tratando de enviar datos mediante un formulario a phpmyadmin, pero no funciona

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($conexion, "frigorifico");
mysqli_query($conexion, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$serie=$_POST['serie1'];
$temperatura = $_POST['temp1'];
mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO `datos` (`id`, `fecha`, `temperatura`, `serie`) VALUES (NULL, current_timestamp(), '$temperatura', '$serie');");
mysqli_close($conexion);
echo"Datos ingresados correctamente"; 
echo "<br>";
echo "serie", $serie;
echo "<br>";
echo "temperatura", $temperatura;

?>
////////
<form action="entrada_datos1.php" method="POST">


    <p> serie: <input type="text" name="serie1" /></p>

    <p> temperatura <input type="text" name="temp1" /></p>
    <p> <input type="submit" /></p>

 </form>
```

ese es el código que use para el formulario.

No me salen mensajes de error ni nada pero los datos no aparecen

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la query por esto:

```
mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO datos (id, fecha, temperatura, serie) VALUES (NULL, current_timestamp(), '".$temperatura."', '".$serie."');");
```

Comment: gracias Maikel, pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Podrías ponerme una foto de la tabla datos ?

Comment: no se como poner fotos

Comment: la estructura al menos(?) con que versión de php estás trabajando? instalaste servidor local?

Answer (score 0):

¿Estas seguro que esta conectando a la base de datos? por mi poca experiencia tengo entendido que esto:

```
mysqli_select_db
```

No se realiza de esta manera, de hecho lo tienes demas ya que si no me equivoco eso se realizaba en las viejas versiones de php, esta funcion ya no se utiliza, elimina esa linea y deja lo siguiente de esta manera

```
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "frigorifico");
```

Esto es debido a que al momento de insertar el codigo lo toma de la siguiente manera:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario", "clave", "basedatos");
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas llamando mal a tu base de datos,

```
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($conexion, "frigorifico");
```

Prueba con;

```
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "frigorifico");
```